# Php. Number of zeros in float

Tags: php, format

I have to send the JSON:

```
{"val": 5000.00}
```

Neither `{"val": "5000.00"}` nor `{"val": 5000}` is correct format.
`json_encode()` converts 5000.00 to 5000

Is it possible to send correct json's format (two zeros) with `json_encode` from
`array("val" => (float) 5000.00)` ?

Comment: Json is for data transfer. For data transfer, you don't want insignificant digits in your numbers. If you want them presented to end user, use e.g. `toFixed()` at the client side before showing.

Comment: You need format you data manually after json_decode(), JSON will deal with data format for you.

Comment: Impossible to do with json_encode AFAIK. Use JSON to transfer data, do not use it to control how the data is presented to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really really** need to do that you may consider two options:

**Option nr. 1:**

You build up the json econded string by your own. If the data you have to encode have a simple structure and that structure is not subject to change in the future the task is easy. You'll have a slower script so another requirement is that the data is not too much.

For a single object like the example you posted...

```
$json = sprintf('{"val": %.2f}', $floatValue);
```

Of course for structured data, like an array of objects, arrays of arrays... you'll have to write the necessary loops, place accurately **, : [ ] { } "**. Hope I gave you the idea...

**Option nr. 2:**

You build up the data you have to encode just as you would if you didn't have the *weird requirement* you asked for. **But** store float values into strings that will also contains some *pattern* characters.
For example you'll store 5000.00 as "##5000.00##"
Encode the data with json_ecode.
Permorm string replacements to eliminate "## and ##"

```
$floatValue = 5000.00;
$data = array("val" => sprintf("##%.2f##", $floatValue));
$json = json_encode($data);
$json = str_replace('"##', '', $json);
$json = str_replace('##"', '', $json);
```

Choose your pattern characters (## in the example) carefully to avoid conflicts with other strings that may contain the same pattern elsewere in you data to be encoded.

Comment: That's not useful advice, that's a lot of wasted effort to produce a JSON string that still won't produce your desired results. Even if you produce the string `{"a": 500.00}`, it will still be parsed as `{a: 500}`, because you **cannot add trailing zeros after the decimal**.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible, because what you think are "correct" and "incorrect" values are actually the same value. It's purely a rendering decision to show/hide trailing zeros.

It's up to you *at display time* to render the value with the correct number of decimal places. You can't *force* a floating point number to be stored or transfered with a certain number of decimals.

Comment: json_encode returns a string. Can I config php to display this zeros?

Comment: Not unless you want to use one of the "formats" you consider invalid... `{"val": "5000.00"}`. Otherwise, a float is a float, and you cannot, in any way, impose extra trailing zeros on it. It's impossible. The only time you get to control how many trailing zeros a "float" has is when it's been converted to a string for display to the user. This is why I said you shouldn't be doing it in the JSON. You should add the trailing zeros later, when you actually show the user the value.

Comment: preg_replace('/:"(\d+\.\d+)",/', ':$1,', json_encode($a, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT))

Answer (score -1):

```
just preg_replace('/:"(\d+\.\d+)",/', ':$1,', json_encode($a, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT))
```

Comment: Sorry, but you don't know what you're doing. You may have successfully produced the string `{"a": 500.00}`, but it is just going to be turned back into `{a: 500}` when you JSON-decode it. Your solution is wrong because you still don't understand the problem. You cannot add trailing zero's to a float.

Comment: Simply put: `JSON.parse('{"a": 500.00}')` => `Object {a: 500}`

Comment: That's completely inappropriate behaviour for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree with you, it'not so wise to try to seem smarter than it is.

Comment: That didn't make any sense, I can't understand what you're saying.